# I need a proof of a theorem about generated group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]
[image]
how to use definition 2.7 to prove theorem 2.8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $H$ be the collection of all finite products $a_1^{n_1} a_2^{n_2} \ldots a_t^{n_t} (a_i \in X, n_i \in \mathbb{Z})$. Check that :

a) $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ (Use the subgroup test : if $x, y\in H$, conclude that $xy^{-1} \in H$)

b) If $K$ is any subgroup of $G$ containing $X$, then $H\subset K$.

Proof : If $X \subset K$, then for any $a_i \in X, n_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a_i^{n_i} \in K$, and hence by closure, $a_1^{n_1} a_2^{n_2}\ldots a_t^{n_t} \in K$. Hence, $H\subset K$

Comment: I need detail about b)

Comment: b) follows from the definition of a subgroup. If you really want a formal proof, use induction on $t$.